# How to get input where a newline exists in Python

Tags: python

I want to receive input where there is a newline in Python.

I want to input a number and I have implemented the following code, but I get the following error

**Code**

```
string = []

while True:
    input_str = int(input(">"))
    if input_str == '':
        break
    else:
        string.append(input_str)
```

**Error**

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

**line error**

```
>1
>2
>3
>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2750.py", line 4, in <module>
    input_str = int(input(">"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: I assume this is Python 2?

Comment: Probably, you need to use raw_input instead of input

Comment: I don't see the line that could be causing the error. In which line are you trying to cast a `string` into an `int`?

Comment: I use python3. raw_input does not seem to be supported.

Comment: Can you show some input you're using and where you're actually calling `int`? It also can't be Python 2.x, as using `input` and just hitting enter will give a `SyntaxError` @roganjosh

Comment: The error occurs at "input_str = int (input ("> "))" when nothing is entered.

Comment: Could you show a desired output?

Comment: @prgnewbies that's not the code you posted... you've got a check for an empty string there... so if the input's empty - skip it... otherwise, then try to convert it to int?

Comment: I added a command line error to the article.

Comment: Please post the actual code you're using. The code you've posted doesn't have this line `input_str = int(input(">"))`

Comment: Yes. I found the problem and corrected it.

Comment: @prgnewbies the linked duplicate addresses best practices and the alternate ways you can handle what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

try isdigit function of string, see below example:

```
string = []

while True:
    input_str = input(">")
    if input_str.isdigit():
        input_str = int(input_str)
    if input_str == '':
        break
    else:
        string.append(input_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a try-except approach:

```
strList = []      
while True:
    try:
     strList.append(int(input('Enter the number > ')))
    except ValueError:
        print ('Invalid number. Please try again!')
        break
print(strList)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter the number > 1
Enter the number > 2
Enter the number > 3
Enter the number > 
Invalid number. Please try again!
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I don't think this is how they want it to behave. They want a check for equality to an empty string for `break` to occur, and the rest should be in a `try`/`except` as you have. The test for equality won't throw an exception and still allows incorrect input to not break out of the loop. This will currently break out on any non-integer-like input.

Comment: @roganjosh my intial thoughts as well. I'd say we see if OP clarifies this and I'll make an edit.